# Let $f:[1,10]\to \Bbb{Q}$ be a continuous function and $f(1)=10,$then $f(10)=?$

Tags: functions

Let $f:[1,10]\to \Bbb{Q}$ be a continuous function and $f(1)=10,$then $f(10)=?$

$(A)\frac{1}{10}\hspace{1 cm}(B)10\hspace{1 cm}(C)1\hspace{1 cm}(D)$cant be obtained

I could not solve this question.I thought over it for many minutes,here $\Bbb{Q}$ is a set of rational numbers.If $f(1)$ is known,can we find $f(10)$?I suspect,Calculus has something to do in the solution.Can someone please help me in this question?

Comment: Hint: [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)  "+" between any two rational numbers, there is...

Comment: @achillehui,Sir i am not able to solve with Intermediate value theorem,i tried.If $f(1)$and $f(10)$ is given,then IMV theorem is applicable?Isn't it?I am confused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose $f(10) = a \neq 10$ where $a$ is a rational. Then by the IVT, every real number between $a$ and $10$ is attained by the function in the interval $[1, 10]$. (Also, if we are strict since IVT usually requires real functions, we are using a generalization of IVT: continuous functions preserve connectedness.)

Now between every 2 distinct rationals, there is an irrational. So the function must have an irrational number in its image. But the codomain of the function is the rational numbers, so this is a contradiction. Hence $f(10) = 10$.

Credit to the comment above.

Comment: Following a discussion on the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), this [generalization of the IVT](http://planetmath.org/connectednessispreservedunderacontinuousmap) is invoked (or at least the reason why the regular IVT can be used needs arguing) because of the phrasing of the question: $f$ is a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, which is not exactly the same as a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f([a,b])\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ . (There are chances the latter is what the original question intended.)